# How to make regex if string contains comma(,) space, and other characters like (

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

I have string:

```
<td class="cspan">Proximates</td>\n\t<td style="text-align:left">Total lipid (fat)\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t</td>\n\t\t\n\t\t<td>g</td>\n\t\t\n\t\t\t<td style="text-align:right;">78.30</td>
```

and I need a regex for it.  I have tried many like this one:

```
Total lipid\(fat\)\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\<\/td\>\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\<td\>g\<\/td\>\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\<td style\=\"text\-align\:right\;\"\>(.*?)\<\/td\>
```

And also I have another string:

```
<td style="text-align:left">Vitamin C, total ascorbic acid\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t</td>\n\t\t\n\t\t<td>mg</td>\n\t\t\n\t\t\t<td style="text-align:right;">0.0</td>
```

and I have tried many regex's for that one also like:

```
Vitamin C\, total ascorbic acid\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\<\/td\>\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\<td\>mg\<\/td\>\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\<td style\=\"text\-align\:right\;\"\>(.*?)\<\/td\>
```

and my third string is:

```
<td style="text-align:left">Vitamin B-12\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t</td>\n\t\t\n\t\t<td>\xb5g</td>\n\t\t\n\t\t\t<td style="text-align:right;">0.07</td>
```

and I have tried this one and more like this:

```
data = re.search('Vitamin B\-12\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\<\/td\>\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\<td\>µg\<\/td\>\\n\\t\\t\\n\\t\\t\\t\<td style\=\"text\-align\:right\;\"\>(.*?)\<\/td\>',tb)
```

From those strings I am trying to get the data which is:

1. from the first string is: 78.30
2. from the second: 0.0
3. from the third: 0.07

I need regex like i have written above with just minor changes because i know i am missing something

Comment: Are you looking for 3 expressions that each find the number or one expression that finds the identifier, number pair? (e.g. data = [(fat, 78.30), (Vit C, 0.0), (Vit B-12, 0.07)] )

Comment: I needed a three regex like i written they are nearly correct but there is one or two mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have discovered, XML (HTML) and regex's do not mix well.  However this problem is quite straight forward when using [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4):

**Code:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(row)
print soup.findAll('td')[-1].text
```

**Test Code:**

```
data = (
    """
    <td class="cspan">Proximates</td>
    <td style="text-align:left">Total lipid (fat)


    </td>
    <td>g</td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">78.30</td>
    """,
    """
    <td style="text-align:left">Vitamin C, total ascorbic acid


    </td>
    <td>mg</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">0.0</td> "
    """,
    """
    <td style="text-align:left">Vitamin B-12


    </td>
    <td>\xb5g</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">0.07</td> "
    """,
)


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for row in data:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(row)
    print soup.findAll('td')[-1].text
```

**Results:**

```
78.30
0.0
0.07
```

Comment: This is a far more robust way to parse the html than a regex which can get tripped up very easily if you don't think of all edge cases. I would recommend https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4 since the one you linked to is deprecated. Only change is import line: "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup"

Comment: I know but I need regex for it 'cause there is not only table like I gave there is lot more rows and columns and I have plain text of table body

Comment: If it is HTML (and you did tag this scrapy) you do not want a regex.  BeautifulSoup will parse it just fine.